# Combo box not getting filled

Tags: c#, list, combobox, using, fill

I have this function which I am using to fill my combobox but its not getting filled. I am not getting any error either.

```
public List<string> showStudents()
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
                string rollno;
                command = connection.CreateCommand(); //command and connection have been initialized earlier..
                command.CommandText = "select RollNo from student";
            try
            {                    
                connection.Open();                
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {                    
                    rollno = reader["RollNo"].ToString();
                    list.Add(rollno);
                }
                reader.Close();
                return list;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}

comboBox.DataSource=showStudents();
```

What may be the problem? Please help!!
Thank You..
Have got the answer.. :)

```
foreach(string str in showStudent())
{
comboBox.Items.Add(str);
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that the reader is actually returning results?

Comment: Ya. I did. It is providing proper result.

Answer (score 0):

If the reader returns results you should set the members "DisplayMember" and "ValueMember" of the ComboBox to tell which column the combox should use for the text displayed and the value of the item.

Like this :

```
comboBox.DisplayMember = "RollNo"
comboBox.ValueMember= "RollNo"
```

You can put it right after setting the DataSource. Tell us if it helps.

Comment: Actually I want to do this through the above function only. Can you tell me how to fill the combobox using fuction that returns the values like above?

Answer (score 0):

See this sample example and try with ur code

```
string Sql = "select Company_ID,company_name from JO.dbo.Comp";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Sql, conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{

     comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
     comboBox1.DataTextField = "company_name";
     comboBox1.DataValueField = "Company_ID";
     comboBox1.DataBind();
     comboBox1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
}
```